# Card reader draining power on MacBook running 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, macbook, card-reader, powertop

I'm using 14.04 on a MacBook Air 5,2 (mid 2012, 13").
I just recently noticed **powertop** listing the built-in card reader to drain massive amounts of power:

```
Power est.    Usage     Device name
  6.68 W    100,0%        USB device: Card Reader (Apple)
  399 mW      2,9%        CPU core
  235 mW      3,9 ops/s   GPU core
 90.2 mW      3,9 ops/s   GPU misc
    0 mW    100,0%        USB device: usb-device-8087-0024
    0 mW    100,0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
```

I've set all USB devices to powersave via **rc.local**:

```
# WLAN
iw dev wlan0 set power_save on;

# PCI general powersaving
for pci in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control;
do echo auto > $pci;
done

# USB general powersaving
for usb in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/control;
do echo auto > $usb;
done

# NMI watchdog
echo '0' > '/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog';

# backlight
echo '3' > '/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness';
exit 0
```

When checking via terminal, it seems the power saving is enabled correctly:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.8.3/idVendor 
05ac
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.8.3/idProduct 
8404
$ lsusb | grep 8404
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:8404 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.8.3/power/control
auto
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.8.3/power/autosuspend
2
```

Haven't noticed this right after installing 14.04. Might have been some kernel update. The card reader is still working correctly in file managers but constantly drains power now.
Any ideas?

Comment: temporary workaround is to issue a `echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.8.3/remove` after every boot, which will get rid of the power drain by disabling the card reader completely.

Comment: Noticing the same problem.

Comment: Same problem here, super-annoying. :-/